# PHP: global Array as temp. storage - dirty or not?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, global-variables, global

I try to avoid `global variables`, but this time I need a way to store and change values temporary, without writing them on the HDD or store them in the memory.

When I was brainstorming, I exclude `cookies`, `sessions`, `memcache` and `local files`.

Here's my simple Idea:

```
$_GLOBAL_DUMP = array();

class GlobalDump {
    public static function set($key, $value) {
        global $_GLOBAL_DUMP;
        $_GLOBAL_DUMP[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        global $_GLOBAL_DUMP;
        return $_GLOBAL_DUMP[$key];
    }
}
```

I could use it like

```
GlobalDump::set("any_key", "my name is foo"); // foo.php
GlobalDump::get("any_key", "my name is bar"); // bar.php
echo GlobalDump::get("any_key"); // echos "my name is bar"
```

I don't like the `$_GLOBAL_DUMP`-array. What do you think? Clean enough or any workarounds/alternatives?

Comment: You can add the `$_GLOBAL_DUMP` array as a static variable of the class itself? So you would do `return GlobalDump::$_GLOBAL_DUMP[$key]; `

Comment: Wow, shame on me. Thanks for your advice. If you'd like to get the reputation, post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I posted an answer now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `$_GLOBAL_DUMP` array as a static variable in the class. You would then access the static variable from within the class itself like this:

```
GlobalDump::$_GLOBAL_DUMP
```